# Chess pieces Unicode tkinter font issues

Tags: python, tkinter, unicode, chess

I'm working on a chess-based game in Python 3 using tkinter windows. I'm using the Unicode characters for chess pieces. However, they have two different looks (as seen here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_symbols_in_Unicode). I want to use the top one, but no matter what font I use, the ugly bottom version appears. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: It would be more convenient to use a monospaced font

Comment: The image litterally states that the top set are the "Arial Unicode MS" and the bottom set is the "Tahoma" font. Arial as standard is not the same as Arial Unicode MS. You may need to seek a dowload and import it into your program to allow the change.

Comment: @Takarii I've managed to use the font (from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
font3 = "-family {@Arial Unicode MS} -size 50"
A = Label(root, text='\u2654', font=font3)
A.pack()
root.mainloop()), but it still shows the bad image.

Comment: The problem is almost certainly that you simply don't have the font you are asking for, so tkinter is substituting another font.

Comment: How can I get the font?

Comment: You can use the `actual` method of a font object to see what the actual font is, and you can use the `families` method of the tkinter font class to get a list of available font families.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is likely that tkinter can't find the font you specified, or the font you specified doesn't have the unicode glyphs, so it's substituting in a font that has the glyphs.

Here's a little program that will show you all of the fonts on your system, and what the chess pieces look like:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info.major is 3:
    import tkinter as tk, tkinter.font as tkFont
else:
    import Tkinter as tk, tkFont

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root, tabs=(200,))
vsb = tk.Scrollbar(root, command=text.yview)
text.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
text.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

pieces = u"\u2654\u2655\u2656\u2657\u2658\u2659\u265A\u265B\u265C\u265D\u265E\u265F\n"
for count, family in enumerate(sorted(tkFont.families())):
    font = tkFont.Font(family=family, size=18)
    tag = "font-%s" % count
    text.tag_configure((tag,), font=font)
    text.insert("end", family)
    text.insert("end", "\t" + pieces, tag)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```
Label(win, text='\u2654', font='Courier 96')
```

provides a pretty nice White King icon (the same as in your Wikipedia link)

To see if the character exists on your system, you may create the following HTML file **test.html**, and open it with your browser to see if it displays the correct icon:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<html><body>
<h1>&#9812;&#9813;</h1>
</body></html>
```

Comment: It still uses the bad version. Code tested:                                           from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
A = Label(root, text='\u2654', font='Courier 96')
A.pack()
root.mainloop()

Comment: The same code provides the nice icon on my computer. You may have some old fonts on your system. What OS are you using?

Comment: I use Windows 10

Comment: OK, I've tried the same code on 3 different computers running last version of Win10, and all three showed the right White King icon. Have no idea about what is different on your system. Sorry.

Comment: It works properly. It shows the correct king and queen.

Comment: Aren't you falling for the same trap? On *my* Windows 10, Courier does not have chess symbols, and it apparently takes them from Segoe UI Symbol. (Which looks different again from the Tahoma one; Tahoma on my system doesn't have chess either.) (After checking: Segoe is the *only* font I have with Chess.)

Comment: As far as I know, on Windows if a given font does not include a given unicode char, the character is borrowed from a full unicode font (usually Segoe UI). So the name of the font does not really matter, as all exotic characters are taken from the same source. This process is done at the OS level, so it should be totally transparent to Python